# Deploy a FULL blockchain INSIDE the browser using javascript

Tags: go-ethereum, remix, blockchain, evm

In Remix there is an option to deploy a blockchain inside the browser for purpose of testing different smart contracts, this is the REMIX VM as shown on the image.

[image: Screenshoot remix VM]

My question is : How can I do the same on my website ? How can I deploy a local EVM blockchain on a webpage using Javascript ?

Thanks !

Comment: I want to deploy a NEW empty blockchain and not the current Ethereum blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of libraries that you could use to implement something like that.

- [@ganache/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ganache/core)
- [@ethereumjs/vm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ethereumjs/vm)